# Cant scanf and printf in risk-v rars

Tags: c, assembly, printf, riscv, rars-simulator

Hello i am a beginer risc-v learner and i want to do a scanf of an int and print it on console
upon searching a lot on the internet i couldnt find how to proper do it, i try
using compiler explorer https://godbolt.org/ i want to use this c code

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main(){    
int number;    
printf("enter a number:");    
scanf("%d",&number);    
printf("number is:%d ",number);    
return 0;  
}
```

and its giving me this risc-v code

```
main:                                   # @main
        addi    sp, sp, -32
        sw      ra, 28(sp)                      # 4-byte Folded Spill
        sw      s0, 24(sp)                      # 4-byte Folded Spill
        addi    s0, sp, 32
        mv      a0, zero
        sw      a0, -20(s0)                     # 4-byte Folded Spill
        sw      a0, -12(s0)
        lui     a0, %hi(.L.str)
        addi    a0, a0, %lo(.L.str)
        call    printf
        lui     a0, %hi(.L.str.1)
        addi    a0, a0, %lo(.L.str.1)
        addi    a1, s0, -16
        call    scanf
        lw      a1, -16(s0)
        lui     a0, %hi(.L.str.2)
        addi    a0, a0, %lo(.L.str.2)
        call    printf
        lw      a0, -20(s0)                     # 4-byte Folded Reload
        lw      s0, 24(sp)                      # 4-byte Folded Reload
        lw      ra, 28(sp)                      # 4-byte Folded Reload
        addi    sp, sp, 32
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "enter a number:"

.L.str.1:
        .asciz  "%d"

.L.str.2:
        .asciz  "number is:%d "
```

but the part
call printf
call scanf
doesnt work and i cant figure how to do such a esy work any tips?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: i dont know.. only the part call printf and call scanf are giving me troubles it says that Symbol "printf" not found in symbol table.

Comment: MARS and RARS and QtSPIM do not support printf & scanf: there is no std C library.  Rather than format-string based I/O, these use individual system calls (via `ecall` for RARS or via `syscall` for MARS/QtSPIM) for each item you want to print or input. So, you cannot run compiler output on RARS without significant changes.  https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars/wiki/Environment-Calls

Comment: Those %hi and %lo functions are also not available on RARS, so instead of doing `lui`/`addi` pair you do one single `la` to the label.

Comment: On RARS/MARS, `main` is not a function, so there is no returning to the caller, have to use the exit `ecall` to quit the program when `main` is finished.

Comment: On RARS/MARS, strings are not allowed in a `.text` section, have to go in the `.data` section

Comment: okok thanks for the help i understand i was doing it the wrong way i need to use ecall to print and scan, the code was not mine was from compiler explorer that didnt have the risc-v rars compiler ty for the help ill try!

Answer (score 0):

linker will give undefined reference error because directly you not compiled it in C instead took assembly code from gcc and gave it to linker.

if you directly compile with c you will get reference to printf and scanf and for risk v you can tell c to give static binary instead of dynamic

If i not understood what you want to know than plz explain

Comment: The OP mentions the RARS simulator.